# Regularity of complex function in region $D$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

We say $f(z)$ is regular in $D$ if for every point $z\in D$, $f$ is differentiable.
The question comes with regards to Cauchy formula and Newton-Leibniz formula for
$$\int_\gamma \frac{1}{4z+iz^2}\mbox{d}z $$
where $\gamma$ is the boundary of a triangle with vertices $-i, 2+i,-2+i$.

Applying the actual formulae is not the problem. However, both Cauchy and N-L are applicable if $f$ is regular in $D$. Clearly, there is a singularity in the triangle at $0$. Can $f$ be regular in $D$ (the triangle), regardless?

Can we still apply these formulae, am I overlooking something?

What about N-L case?

Comment: $f(z) = g(z)/z$, where $g(z) = -i/(z-4i)$. The function $g$ is regular in $D$ and continuous on $\overline D$.

Comment: Is the following assertation meaningful?  
$$\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_\gamma\frac{\frac{1}{4+i\zeta}}{\zeta - 0}\mbox{d}\zeta = f(0) $$

Comment: If $f=\frac{1}{4+i\zeta}$ (edit: and $\gamma$ encloses the origin but not $4i$), then yes.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to point you to. :o)

Comment: @bartgol What can we say about the N-L case, though? I need a primitive for the entire $\frac{1}{4z+iz^2}$, but singularity occurs in $D$, does that mean game over? The theorem does state a primitive exists if $f$ is regular. I just hope there is no magical way around this one.

Comment: Actually, the theorem. further requires $f$ to be bounded in the triangle. There can be no boundedness at a singularity, right?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with Newton-Leibniz formula. Google tells me it's the FTC. If it's that, then you do need to find a primitive of $f$. You can do that with partial fractions. The singularity is not a problem, cause it does not lie on the path where you are integrating on. However, there is the branch cut for the log to keep into account when you evaluate the primitive.

Comment: @bartgol Confused again. Isn't it $\int_a^b f(t)\mbox{d}t = F(b)- F(a)$? Meaning I need $F$ to do anything. The ftc given in our textbook states that $f$ must be regular and bounded in $D$ for the $F$ to exist.
Why is the singularity not a problem, it lies in $D$ and violates the pre requirement. :(

Comment: The function needs to be regular over the set where you integrate. Your integral is over the boundary of the triangle, not over the triangle itself. Your function is regular over the boundary of the triangle.